# ng-server reload page but not really update until I manually refresh

Tags: angular, angular-cli, hot-reload

The app development using 'ng serve' has been fine.

But recently, even though, the browser refreshes itself after some changes in Angular code while running `ng serve`. I have to manually refresh page.

I tried `ng serve`, `ng serve --hmr` and `ng serve --hmr --poll=2000`. All has no go.

I also did

```
echo "fs.inotify.max_user_watches=524288" | sudo tee -a /etc/sysctl.conf
sudo sysctl -p
```

```
Angular CLI: 16.2.6
Node: 18.13.0
Package Manager: npm 8.19.3
OS: linux x64

Angular: 16.2.10
... animations, common, compiler, compiler-cli, core, forms
... localize, platform-browser, platform-browser-dynamic, router

Package                         Version
---------------------------------------------------------
@angular-devkit/architect       0.1602.6
@angular-devkit/build-angular   16.2.6
@angular-devkit/core            16.2.6
@angular-devkit/schematics      16.2.6
@angular/cdk                    16.2.9
@angular/cli                    16.2.6
@angular/material               16.2.9
@schematics/angular             16.2.6
rxjs                            7.5.7
typescript                      4.9.5
zone.js                         0.13.3
```

I use wsl2 on win10. VS code does port forwarding.

Comment: most probably browser cache issue . Been seeing that in chrome.

Comment: True. I was using Chrome. Switched to Edge. It's good now.

Comment: maybe use incognito mode or clean data in chrome